# All possible pairs of two items

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, algorithm

I have 4 different items `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. I want to obtain all possible pairs of two of the items. I have written:

```
n = 4;
x1 = Tuples[Range@n, n];

Cases[x1, {a_, a_, b_, b_} /; a != b]
```

gives the desired result:

> {{1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4, 4}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 3, 3}}

Now I choose

```
n = 6;
x2 = Tuples[Range@n, n];

Cases[x2, {a_, a_, b_, b_, c_, c_} /; a != b && a != c && b != c];
% // Short
```

> {{1,1,2,2,3,3},{1,1,2,2,4,4},<<116>>,{6,6,5,5,3,3},{6,6,5,5,4,4}}

again gives the desired result.

How would you automate this (for even `n`)?

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: @Szabolcs Well almost, but not quite. For `Subsets` you'll need to generate additional permutations in order to get the desired output, and for `Tuples` you'll need to throw away cases of repeated pairs.

Comment: @Öska Thanks for the edit and `Short`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another approach:

```
pairRiffle[n_?EvenQ] := Riffle[#, #] & /@ (Permutations[Range@n, {n/2}])

pairRiffle[4]
(* {{1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4, 4}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 
  3}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 
  1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 3, 3}} *)
```

---

**Edit**: in fact I could do without the Riffle and just use the transformation rule in @Teake Nutma's answer

```
pairHybrid[n_?EvenQ] :=  Permutations[Range@n, {n/2}] /. x_Integer -> Sequence[x, x]

pairHybrid[10] == Sort@AllPairs[10]
(* True *)
pairRiffle[10] == Sort@AllPairs[10]
(* True *)
```

Comment: +1 for the second argument of `Permutations`.

Comment: Thanks! +1 to you too for the inspiration.

Comment: @seismatica +1 A funny development :)

Comment: Nice use of `Riffle`!  That's my favorite way to double elements.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the job:

```
AllPairs[n_?EvenQ] := 
   Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[Range[n], {n/2}], 1] /. x_Integer :> Sequence[x, x]

AllPairs[4]
```

> ```
> {
>   {1, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 1, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, 
>   {2, 2, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 3, 3}
> }
> ```